# Is there a name for this property: If $a\sim b$ and $c\sim b$ then $a\sim c$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $X$ be a set with a binary relation $\sim$, such that for all $a$, $b$, and $c$ in $X$:

> If $a\sim b$ and $c\sim b$ then $a\sim c$

Is anyone familiar with this property of a binary relation? Does it have a name? Does it have any interesting properties?

Comment: It implies reflexivity anyway.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy It doesn't, consider the empty relation.

Comment: The empty relation is vacuously transitive, @Christoph. Furthermore, the given relation is non-empty.

Comment: @Student No relation is given, just a property of a relation. This property is satisfied by the empty relation, since the premise "$a\sim b$ and $c\sim b$" is never true in this case, so the implication holds. However, the empty relation (on non-empty sets) is certainly not reflexive.

Comment: I see, @Christoph, a relation with the Euclidean property may indeed be the empty relation.

Comment: Thank you @Christoph of course you are correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called (left) Euclidean relation. You can find more at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_relation). Using a diagram:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
a && c\\
\downarrow&\swarrow \\
b
\end{array}
\hspace{20pt}\text{implies}\hspace{20pt}
\begin{array}{c}
a &\rightarrow& c\\
\downarrow&\swarrow \\
b
\end{array}
$$

Some interesting properties (I'm using the left- version, it would be the similar for right-Euclidean):

- If $\sim$ is symmetric and Euclidean then it is also transitive:
  $$a \sim b \land b \sim c \xrightarrow{\text{sym.}} a \sim b \land c \sim b \xrightarrow{\text{Eucl.}} a \sim c.$$
- If $\sim$ is reflexive and Euclidean then it is also symmetric:
  $$a \sim b \xrightarrow{\text{refl.}} b \sim b \land a \sim b  \xrightarrow{\text{Eucl.}} b \sim a.$$
- For all $a$, existence of $b$ such that $a \sim b$ implies $a \sim a$ (for left-Euclidean):
  $$a \sim b \xrightarrow{\text{copy}} a \sim b \land a \sim b \xrightarrow{\text{Eucl.}} a \sim a.$$
- For all $a$, existence of $b$ such that $b \sim a$ does not need to imply anything (for left-Euclidean), for example (note that reflexivity does not work for $b$):
  $$
  \begin{array}{c}
  a && c\\
  \downarrow&\swarrow \\
  b
  \end{array}
  \hspace{20pt}\text{implies}\hspace{20pt}
  \begin{array}{c}
  \stackrel{\curvearrowleft}a &\rightarrow& \stackrel{\curvearrowleft}c\\
  \downarrow&\swarrow \\
  b
  \end{array}
  $$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Is there any "classical" example of left (or right) Euclidean relation? Wikipedia does not give one, except the formalization of Euclides elements.

Comment: @Taladris I don't know of any, if there are, these are equivalence relations.