# Is there a term for irreflexive relations whose reflexive closures are equivalence relations?

Tags: terminology, relations, equivalence-relations

Consider a relation $\sim$ which is irreflexive, that is:

$$
\forall A \:A\nsim A
$$

Further suppose the reflexive closure of $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.  The reflexive closure of $\sim$, denoted $\simeq$, is defined like this:

$$
\forall A \forall B \:A\simeq B \iff A \sim B \vee A = B
$$

(in other words, it's formed by unioning the $\sim$ relation with the equality relation)

Is there a standard name for relations like this?

I thought of this while reading [a rather interesting discussion](http://qntm.org/gay) of database schemas in the context of same-sex and plural marriages.  The relation I describe above corresponds to "is-married-to" in one of those schemas.  Since people cannot marry themselves, it is irreflexive, but it's otherwise structured as an equivalence relation.

Comment: Perhaps you would be interested in [Euclidean relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_relation), see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/765687/26306).

Comment: I skimmed the discussion you linked, and in that case I would say that you are looking for a term like (to sound fancy) nowhere injective partial functions (which map `human_id`-s to `marriage_id`-s), although the irreflexivity seems IMO silly from mathematical point of view, not only it is just data representation, but when you introduce polygamy (as that site does), then it just unnecessarily introduces another corner case.